# Windows 7 Installer does not recognize my hard drive

Tags: windows-7, sata, pci-express

I recently bought a PCI-Express card to add additional Sata ports to my desktop [(this one)](http://www.amazon.it/DeLOCK-SATA-PCI-Express-Card/dp/B000M8FTRO/ref=sr_1_13?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1353668613&sr=1-13]his).

Within my other SO the hard drives connected to the PCI-E card are recognized and working fine.

But, when I try to boot from PCI-E card's connected hard drive, an old Windows7 installation gives me a BSOD on startup.

Then, I tried to reinstall Windows 7, but the windows 7 installer doesn't recognize the hard disk connected through the PCI-E card, so I can't install it.

What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that the installer doesn't recognize your SATA card, you need to supply the installer with the SATA drivers for your card. A tutorial can be found [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/68505-sata-driver-load-windows-7-vista-setup.html), but just to outline:

- Get the drivers for your SATA card onto a USB stick or other accessable media
- Proceed until Windows 7 installer asks "Where do you want to install Windows?"
- Click the `Load driver` link
- Click `Cancel` and the `Browse...` to manually search for the driver
- Browse to the directory which contains your drivers
- If necessary, close the warning about no suitable drivers, and uncheck the `Hide drivers...` checkbox (Be careful with this!)
- Choose the correct driver from the list and click `Next`
- Your drive should now be visible in the list!